# WPF TextBlock not displaying underscore

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock

I have this block of code in a dropdown control:

```
    <ComboBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Grid>
                <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton" 
                              Grid.Column="2" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                              Focusable="false"                           
                              ClickMode="Press" 
                              HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" >
                    <ToggleButton.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="18"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

   . . . . 

                                <Border x:Name="BorderComp" 
                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                        CornerRadius="0" 
                                        Margin="1" 
                                        Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrushKey}}"
                                        BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" >

                                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Text,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" 
                                                 Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrushKey}}"
                                                 Padding="2" />
                                </Border>
```

When the text to display contains an underscore, the underscore is not displayed on screen.  I use Snoop to check the values and the `Text` value does contain the underscore.  For instance, `X_9999` is displayed as `X9999`.

I find a number of postings explaining that underscores are used as an accelerator on `Labels`, but this is not supposed to affect `TextBlock`.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I found the issue to be within the `ComboBox.ItemTemplate` which was defined as follows:

```
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Title}"
                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      Tag="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}"
                      Click="CheckBox_Click" />
            </CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

I changed to the following and everything works correctly now.  Apparently `Checkbox` uses a `Label` by default.

```
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      Tag="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}"
                      Click="CheckBox_Click">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
            </CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Maybe you could use a converter that creates two underscores for each single underscore ? AFAIK two underscores are displayed as one.

Comment: Are you saying that you don't see the underscore for a TextBlock like this?: <TextBlock Text="X_9999" />. I certainly do.

Comment: Did you test what happens if the text contains double underscores? Does it appear as one, or both are missing? Or, did you check if setting `RecognizesAccessKey` to false has any effect?

Comment: OK, got exactly the same problem when displaying a string containing an underscore in a plain Label control e.g '64_12' displays as '6412'. Has to be something to do with the 'ContentStringFormat' (?) property of the underlying Content Control (?). Anyone got any suggestions?